# Question regarding Ito Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am new to Ito Process, so I have a following question. 
Consider a standard Ito Process, 
$$X_t=X_0+\int_0^t\mu_sds+\int_0^t\sigma_sdW_s$$
where W is the m-dimentional Brownian motion and X is a n-dimentional process. 
$\mu$ and $\sigma$ are adaptive to {$\Sigma_t$} generated by the Brownian motion. In somewhere in my textbook, it says the drift and the variance can be derived as following,
$$\frac{d}{ds} E(X_s|\Sigma_t)|_{s=t}= \mu_t $$ and 
$$\frac{d}{ds} Var(X_s|\Sigma_t)|_{s=t}= \sigma_t\sigma_t^T$$ 
I thought this is trivial and attempted to prove it myself, however it took me nearly an hour, and can't even show the first one..

I tried the following way, 
$$\frac{d}{ds} E(X_s|\Sigma_t)|_{s=t}= \frac{d}{ds} E(X_0+\int_0^s\mu_sds+\int_0^s\sigma_sdW_s|\Sigma_t)|_{s=t}$$$$=\frac{d}{ds} E(X_0|\Sigma_t)+\frac{d}{ds}E(\int_0^s\mu_sds)+\frac{d}{ds}E(\int_0^s\sigma_sdW_s|\Sigma_t))$$

Then I feel that the last term should be zero by the independent increment property, but not 100% sure I can use here, inside the integral there is $\sigma_s$, then I don't know how to proceed from here and get the above two equation.

Any help will be extremely appreciated!!

Comment: @ papayan: Hints : For the first one what about martingale property of stochastic integrals. For the second one use Itô's isometry.

Comment: @ TheBridge..Thank you for the hint, this helps me a lot. But I am still stuck at the first step, by using the martingale property I have $$\frac{d}{ds} E(X_s|\Sigma_t)|_{s=t}= \frac{d}{ds} E(X_0+\int_0^s\mu_sds+\int_0^s\sigma_sdW_s|\Sigma_t)|_{s=t}$$$$=\frac{d}{ds} E(X_0|\Sigma_t)+\frac{d}{ds}E(\int_0^s\mu_sds|\Sigma_t)$$ the last term becomes zero because of martingale propery of ito integrals, then how to process the second term? Can we exchange the expectation and the differentiation in this case?

Comment: The last term on the RHS does not "become zero". The first term on the LHS is zero, as the derivative with respect to $s$ of a quantity independent of $s$.

Comment: @Did Thank you so much! The last term I meant in the previous message is $\frac{d}{ds}E(\int_0^s\sigma_sdW_s|\Sigma_t)$ which I believe is zero..(if not please let me know..) and yes, the first term is also zero. My question still is that does the following hold? $$\frac{d}{ds}E(\int_0^s\mu_sds|\Sigma_t)=E(\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^s\mu_sds|\Sigma_t) = \mu_t$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since

$$(t,\omega) \mapsto \int_0^t \sigma_r \, dW_r$$

is a martingale, we have for $s \geq t$

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X_s \mid \Sigma_t) &= \mathbb{E}(X_0 \mid \Sigma_t) + \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^s \mu_r \, dr \mid \Sigma_t \right) + \int_0^t \sigma_r \, dW_r \end{align*}$$

Using Fubini's theorem it's not difficult to show that

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^s \mu_r \, dr \mid \Sigma_t \right) = \int_0^s \mathbb{E}(\mu_r \mid \Sigma_t) \, dr$$

Thus,

$$\frac{d}{ds} \mathbb{E}(X_s \mid \Sigma_t) = \frac{d}{ds} \int_0^s \mathbb{E}(\mu_r \mid \Sigma_t) \, dr$$

Assuming that $\mathbb{E}(\mu_r \mid \Sigma_t)$ is a sufficiently nice function, we obtain by the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$\frac{d}{ds} \mathbb{E}(X_s \mid \Sigma_t) \bigg|_{t=s} = \mathbb{E}(\mu_s \mid \Sigma_t) \bigg|_{t=s} = \mu_t$$

(The last equality sign holds since $\mu$ is $\Sigma_t$-adapted.)

The proof of the second equality is rather similar. As @TheBridge already mentioned, it's based on Itô's isometry.

Comment: @papayoan You are welcome. By the way, you can upvote answers which satisfy you.